# How to use scipy.linalg.solve_banded to solve Ax = b when A is a striped matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

To solve a linear equation system

```
Ax=b
```

in which A is a striped matrix like

[image]

who has 5 non-zero diagonals.

But unlike a banded matrix, A has three non-zero diagonals whose offsets are 0, -1, and 1, and two non-zeros diagonals with offsets of -m and m.

I tried directly solving it with

```
diagonals = [Ap, As, An, Aw, Ae]
A = diags(diagonals, [0, -1, 1, -m, m]).toarray()
x = linalg.solve(A, b)
```

This method created the whole A. But A is spares so this method wasted too many memories to save zero elements.

So I tried using solve_banded

```
A = np.zeros((2 * m + 1, len(initial)))
A[0] = Ae
A[m - 1] = An
A[m] = Ap
A[m + 1] = As
A[2 * m] = Aw
x = linalg.solve_banded((m, m), A, b)
```

This method costs less memories than the previous ones, but it still wasted some on (2m-4) zero vectors. Is there any smarter methods which uses only the five non-zero vectors?

Answer (score 4):

Hey I can partially answer this question. To reduce the memory storage, you can maintain the sparse matrix form, without turning it to large matrix by dropping `to.array()` command:

```
A = diags(diagonals, [0, -1, 1, -m, m])
```

Now sparse matrix has its own `spsolve` method and hence `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,b)` will work.

To boost performance further, you can `sparse.linalg.splu(A).solve(b)` which converts A by LU-decomposition and then the SuperLU object again have a `solve` method. (As I tested, this method is slightly faster than directly `spsolve`, which also uses a LU-like decomposition. See [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/memory-and-time-requirements-of-the-scipy-sparse-spsolve) for instance.)

The only problem here is in midst of LU-decomposition the memory usage will also be huge due to decomposition.

I was also wondering if there is any way to synthesise the `solve_banded` method with sparse matrix, as there is no inherent method.